# importing restkit JSONParser error

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I am using restkit inside my project i tried to setup the configuration of the parser
by :

```
[[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] setParserClass:[RKJSONParserJSONKit class] forMIMEType:@"text/javascript"];
```

I imported the library of the parser as in restkit documentation

```
#import <RestKit/JSONKit.h>
```

but always the error

> **Use of undeclared identifier 'RKJSONParserJSONKit'**

also i tried to fix it by importing the header from its location by :

```
#import <RestKit/Code/Support/Parsers/JSON/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h>
```

it does not work , but when i tried to copy the required files for the parser and add it to my project as files the liker give me:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKJSONParserJSONKit in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKJSONParserJSONKit.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKJSONParserJSONKit.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKJSONParserJSONKit in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKJSONParserJSONKit.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKJSONParserJSONKit.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RKLogInitialize in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKLog.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKLog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RKLogConfigureFromEnvironment in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKLog.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKLog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RKLogLevelForString in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKLog.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKLog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RKLogValidationError in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKLog.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKLog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RKLogIntegerAsBinary in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKLog.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(RKLog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _lcl_configure_by_component in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol _lcl_configure_by_identifier in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_component_identifier in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol _lcl_configure_by_header in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_component_header in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol _lcl_configure_by_name in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_component_name in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_level_header in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_level_header_1 in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_level_header_3 in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_level_name in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   duplicate symbol __lcl_version in:
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Intermediates/ReserveOutApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReserveOutApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/lcl.o
>       /Users/reserveout/Desktop/ReserveOutApplication/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a(lcl.o)
>   ld: 19 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. RestKit is configured by default to use JSONKit
2. Your import is wrong, this doesn't import what you want.

try this one but this is Wile E. Coyote's solution

```
#import "RestKit/Code/Support/Parsers/JSON/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h"
```

3. If you really want to copy resources, copy only header file, not source (.m)